# How to customize PMD configuration file generated by Sonar from pom.xml?

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

I would like to activate `protectedAllowed` option from checkStyle in my pom.xml.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to configure the PMD file generated by Sonar is to modify the quality profile that you are using. To do so, you have to log in the Web admin console and go to the "Quality profiles" section (you may have to create a profile of your own if you're using the default one - this is easy, you just copy it)

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+profiles for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to activate protectedAllowed right in the code instead ? lie this for instance in a comment : // protectedAllowed = true

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. The best is to define a new quality profile and customize the appropriate PMD rule to match your needs.